# microsoft graph api - mismatch between cid attachment names in email message body, and the names of attachments return via API call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using curl to

1. list email messages (and their bodies, of course)
2. read their attachments without value- i.e.. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/messages/{MessageId}/attachments?$select=name,id,contentType,isInline](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUserId%7D/messages/%7BMessageId%7D/attachments?$select=name,id,contentType,isInline),
3. read attachment raw content e.g. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/messages/{MessageId}/attachments/{AttachmentId}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BUserId%7D/messages/%7BMessageId%7D/attachments/%7BAttachmentId%7D/$value)

(I read the raw data of attachments on a separate call because it is presumably faster than getting it in a Base64 format together with #2 API call).

Some messages have inline attachments (CID attachment references) in the body, and I am trying to replace these references with Base64 of #3, based on the match between the CID name and the name I am getting from #2.

Example :
#1 message body contains: <img  src="cid:image001.png@01D8D9DB.51722550" .
#2 API call contains {..."isInline" : true, "name" : "image001.png",...} . Here there is a match in names, and I can preform the replacement using the value from #3.

However sometimes the attachment names from #2 do not match the CID attachment names from the body
For example, the attachment names from API call #2 are
image001, image002...
while the CID references are
<img src="cid:183b27ac45e855d34"...,
<img src="cid:183b27ac45fbda4f17" alt="cid:image007.png@01D869CB.F672DCF0" ...

How to find how to match these names?